# Linux - Send STDOUT of command to an RSS Feed

Tags: linux, rss, stdout

I'm looking to use a personal RSS Feed for system reporting, so I'm wondering if it's possible to create a script that sends its $1 to an RSS feed, ala `self_test_command > rss_report.sh`. I don't currently have an RSS feed set up, either, so what would be the easiest way to set up an RSS feed running from a Linux box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a proper solution for you, in `command line`. That use Perl [Template::Toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/) module in background (no need to learn Perl just now) :

first install the package `perl-template-toolkit`, then create the template file `rss.tpl` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <channel>
    <title>[% title %]</title>
    <description>[% desc %]</description>
  </channel>
  <!-- rest of the RSS -->
</rss>
```

And run the command :

```
tpage --define title=foobar --define desc=description --interpolate rss.tpl
```

Output is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <channel>
    <title>foobar</title>
    <description>description</description>
  </channel>
  <!-- rest of the RSS -->
</rss>
```

You will find a complete template to modify [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern)

Comment: Only difference is that on my distro (Debian Squeeze), package was named libtemplate-perl. Otherwise, perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

There is another solution using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

Create an initial rss feed file feed.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>My RSS Feed</title>
    <description>This is my RSS Feed</description>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Create a shell script that uses [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to add items:

```
#!/bin/sh

TITLE="My RSS entry"
LINK="http://example.com/entry4711"
DATE="`date`"
DESC="Good news"
GUID="http://example.com/entry4711" 

xmlstarlet ed -L   -a "//channel" -t elem -n item -v ""  \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n title -v "$TITLE" \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n link -v "$LINK" \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n pubDate -v "$DATE" \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n description -v "$DESC" \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n guid -v "$GUID" \
     -d "//item[position()>10]"  feed.xml ;
```

To have a generic solution one would prefer passing the parameters from the commandline of course.

The -d command ensures that the feed does not grow inifinet but has at most 10 items.