# XMLStarlet - UTF-8 Nordic characters

Tags: xml, utf-8, rss, xmlstarlet

Using XMLStarlet (windows) to edit an RSS feed, but got a few issues with norwegian characters 'ÆØÅ'.

I'm using an example I found at this site ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/14397390/3168446 )

This is my feed.xml. (Notepad++ says it's encoded in UTF-8)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>My RSS Feed</title>
    <description>This is my RSS Feed</description>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

I'm not using the following example as it's for a linux script, but my long command line below does the same-ish..

```
#!/bin/sh

TITLE="Test title ÆØÅ"
LINK="http://www.example.com"
DATE="`Sat, 26 Jul 2014 01:14:30 +0200`"

xmlstarlet ed -L   -a "//channel" -t elem -n item -v ""  \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n title -v "$TITLE" \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n link -v "$LINK" \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n pubDate -v "$DATE" \
     -d "//item[position()>10]"  feed.xml ;
```

Windows command line (what I'm using):

```
xml.exe ed -L -a "//channel" -t elem -n item -v "" -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n title -v "Test title ÆØÅ" -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n link -v "http://www.example.com" -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n pubDate -v "Sat, 26 Jul 2014 01:14:30 +0200" -d "//item[position()>10]" feed.xml
```

'ÆØÅ' is giving me issues when I add the second item containing 'ÆØÅ', well, actually the first item gives me problems, but doesn't produce an error message until second item is added:

```
feed.xml:8.23: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xC6 0xD8 0xC5 0x3C: Bytes: 0xC6 0xD8 0xC5 0x3C

    <title>Test title ãÏ┼</title>
```

Anyone got any tips? I guess it's an encoding issue, but I don't understand why because feed.xml is UTF-8 and encoding is set to utf-8 in the feed.

Comment: The problem is the command line arguments are not encoded as UTF-8, I'm investigating a fix [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25070252/319698)

Comment: Figured it was something like that. I'm using the workaround below until a solution is found, but I find it a bit strange that a cygwin build works as I'm still running it from windows command line and not from within the cygwin terminal.

Comment: Version 1.6.1+ should handle this correctly.

Comment: Fantastic! I've confirmed this and changed the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm this problem is solved in XMLStarlet version 1.6.1+ win32 build!