# How to detect the character encoding of command line arguments in mingw

Tags: c, windows, unicode, mingw

Is it safe to assume they are ISO-8859-15 (Window-1252?), or is there some function I can call to query this? The end goal is to conversion to UTF-8.

---

#### Background:

The problem described by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24984162/319698) arises because XMLStarlet assumes its command line arguments are UTF-8. Under Windows it seems they are actually ISO-8859-15 (Window-1252?), or at least adding the following to the beginning of `main` makes things work:

```
char **utf8argv = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (argc+1));
utf8argv[argc] = NULL;

{
    iconv_t windows2utf8 = iconv_open("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-15");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        const char *arg = argv[i];
        size_t len = strlen(arg);
        size_t outlen = len*2 + 1;
        char *utfarg = malloc(outlen);

        char *out = utfarg;
        size_t ret = iconv(windows2utf8,
            &arg, &len,
            &out, &outlen);

        if (ret < 0) {
            perror("iconv");
            utf8argv[i] = NULL;
            continue;
        }

        out[0] = '\0';
        utf8argv[i] = utfarg;
    }

    argv = utf8argv;
}
```

---

#### Testing Encoding

The following program prints out the bytes of its first argument in decimal:

```
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++) {
        printf("%d ", (unsigned char) argv[1][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

`chcp` reports code page [850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), so the characters æ and Æ should be 145 and 146, respectively.

```
C:\Users\npostavs\tmp>chcp
Active code page: 850
```

But we see 230 and 198 reported which matches [1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_1252):

```
C:\Users\npostavs\tmp>cmd-chars æÆ
230 198
```

#### Passing characters outside of codepage causes lossy transformation

Making a shortcut to `cmd-chars.exe` with arguments `αβγ` (these are not present in codepage 1252) gives

```
C:\Users\npostavs\tmp>shortcut-cmd-chars.lnk
97 223 63
```

Which is `aß?`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call [CommandLineToArgvW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx) with a call to [GetCommandLineW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx) as the first argument to get the command-line arguments in an `argv`-style array of wide strings. This is the only portable Windows way, especially with the code page mess; Japanese characters can be passed via a Windows shortcut for example. After that, you can use [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) with a code page argument of `CP_UTF8` to convert each wide-character `argv` element to UTF-8.

Note that calling `WideCharToMultiByte` with an output buffer size (byte count) of 0 will allow you to determine the number of UTF-8 bytes required for the number of characters specified (or the entire wide string including the null terminator if you wish to pass -1 as the number of wide characters to simplify your code). Then you can allocate the required number of bytes using `malloc` et al. and call `WideCharToMultiByte` again with the correct number of bytes instead of 0. If this was performance-critical, a different solution would probably be best, but since this is a one-time function to get command-line arguments, I'd say any decrease in performance would be negligible.

Of course, don't forget to free all of your memory, including calling `LocalFree` with the pointer returned by `CommandLineToArgvW` as the argument.

For more info on the functions and how you can use them, click the links to see the MSDN documentation.

Comment: Good point about arguments via shortcut, it seems characters outside of the codepage get transliterated on a best effort basis by the system, so this solution is the only one guaranteed to get the correct characters.

Answer (score 2):

The command-line parameters are in the system default codepage, which varies depending on system settings.  Rather than specify a specific source charset at all, you can specify `"char"` or `""` instead and let `iconv_open()` figure out what the system charset actually is:

```
iconv_t windows2utf8 = iconv_open("UTF-8", "char");
```

Otherwise, you are better off retrieving the command-line as UTF-16 instead of as Ansi, and then you can convert it directly to UTF-8 using `iconv_open("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE")`, or `WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8)` like Chrono suggested.

Comment: Oh, I missed that option. Though it does make me wonder how libiconv figures out the encoding.

Comment: libiconv is open source, so you can look for yourself exactly what it does.  I have not looked myself, but I suspect it uses [`GetACP()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318070.aspx) or similar and then maps the reported codepage to its corresponding charset.

Comment: So it does, [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/libiconv.git/tree/libcharset/lib/localcharset.c?id=1bd8e101afd5e2edf63ffcb10328ef4262b375e9#n457). It looks like it supports at least some code pages explicitly, eg: [cp1252](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/libiconv.git/tree/lib/cp1252.h)

Answer (score -2):

It seems that you are under windows.

In this case, you can make a `system()` call to run the `CHCP` command.

```
   #include <stdlib.h>     // Uses: system()
   #include <stdio.h> 
   // ..... 

   // 1st: Store the present windows codepage in a text file:
   system("CMD /C \"CHCP > myenc.txt\"");

   // 2nd: Read the first line in the file:
   FILE *F = fopen("myenc.txt", "r");      
   char buffer[100];
   fgets(buffer, F);
   fclose(F);

   // 3rd: Analyze the loaded string to find the Windows codepage:
   int codepage = my_CHCP_analizer_func(buffer);   

   // The function my_CHCP_analizer_func() must be written for you,
   // and it has to take in account the way in that CHCP prints the information.
```

Finally, the codepages sent by CHCP can be checked for example here:

[Windows Codepages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page)

Comment: I don't think this works, `CHCP` tells me I'm on code page 850, but when I look at the actual values my program receives, they match 1252.

Comment: The codepages 850 and 1252 are similar. Please, study in more detail the Windows codepages in the link I have provided. The value 850 is right. It is the codepage used in Command Line. You can change it to 1252, if needed.

Comment: No, they are different. See the example program I added to the question under **Testing Encoding** heading.

Comment: Ok, I deserve the downvote. I'll face it and I won't delete my answer, anyway.