# XMLStarlet - Adding RSS feed items

Tags: rss, xmlstarlet

Been using an example I found here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14397390/3168446) and I just noticed it's not adding items correctly. The following example is actually adding items outside of the channel-tag. Anyone know the correct way to make this work?

feed.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>My RSS Feed</title>
    <description>This is my RSS Feed</description>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

TITLE="My RSS entry"
LINK="http://example.com/entry4711"
DATE="`date`"
DESC="Good news"
GUID="http://example.com/entry4711" 

xmlstarlet ed -L   -a "//channel" -t elem -n item -v ""  \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n title -v "$TITLE" \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n link -v "$LINK" \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n pubDate -v "$DATE" \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n description -v "$DESC" \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n guid -v "$GUID" \
     -d "//item[position()>10]"  feed.xml ;
```

windows command line example:

```
xml ed -L -a "//channel" -t elem -n item -v "" -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n title -v "My RSS entry" -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n link -v "http://example.com/entry4711" -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n pubDate -v "Sat, 26 Jul 2014 01:14:30 +0200" -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n description -v "Good news" -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n guid -v "http://example.com/entry4711" -d "//item[position()>10]" feed.xml
```

output feed.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>My RSS Feed</title>
    <description>This is my RSS Feed</description>
  </channel>
  <item>
    <title>My RSS entry</title>
    <link>http://example.com/entry4711</link>
    <pubDate>Sat, 26 Jul 2014 01:14:30 +0200</pubDate>
    <description>Good news</description>
    <guid>http://example.com/entry4711</guid>
  </item>
</rss>
```

As you see in the output the item is added outside of the channel-tag so the feed won't validate.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't actually that hard after a good night sleep.

The reason every item is added outside of the channel tag is because I used;

```
xml ed -L -a "//channel"
```

Solution is to use a tag in the feed-template that is not used within the items you're adding. I'm using the generator-tag.

Example feed.xml with added generator-tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>My RSS Feed</title>
    <description>This is my RSS Feed</description>
    <link>http://example.com/entry4711</link>
    <generator>your-rss-generator</generator>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Shell script where I replace //channel with //generator:

```
#!/bin/sh

TITLE="My RSS entry"
LINK="http://example.com/entry4711"
DATE="`date`"
DESC="Good news"
GUID="http://example.com/entry4711" 

xmlstarlet ed -L   -a "//generator" -t elem -n item -v ""  \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n title -v "$TITLE" \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n link -v "$LINK" \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n pubDate -v "$DATE" \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n description -v "$DESC" \
     -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n guid -v "$GUID" \
     -d "//item[position()>10]"  feed.xml ;
```

Windows command line where I replace //channel with //generator:

```
xml ed -L -a "//generator" -t elem -n item -v "" -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n title -v "My RSS entry" -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n link -v "http://example.com/entry4711" -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n pubDate -v "Sat, 26 Jul 2014 01:14:30 +0200" -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n description -v "Good news" -s "//item[1]" -t elem -n guid -v "http://example.com/entry4711" -d "//item[position()>10]" feed.xml
```

This will make every new item go within the channel-tag.

Comment: For Windows command line, `^` is equivalent to shell script ``\``